# Vector push_back error

Tags: c++, class, vector

So this is the situation.

I have a class

```
Class L_FullQuote
{
    private:
    vector<int> time;
    ..
}
```

and

```
Class B
{

    L_FullQuote *Symbols[100];

    void handle message()

}
```

Inside handle msg
i have this statement

```
Symbols[i]->time.push_back(2);
```

the code builds fine..but when i use the generated dll. the application just crashes..sometimes it takes me to a nxt poiner error in vector..but mostly the whole application just crashes.
It works fine without that line.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever initialize the elements of the `Symbols` array to point to `L_FullQuote` objects, or are you using uninitialized pointers?

Comment: I would suggest taking a close look at @Chad's answer.  I answered your question directly, but he proposes a better overall solution.

Answer (score 2):

You're already using `vector`, so why not take it one step further?  Using `std::vector` will allow you to focus on writing your functionality, rather than worrying about memory management.

This example differs slightly from what you originally posted.  Your original question class `B` has an array of 100 pointers that each must be initialized.  In the example below, we create a `std::vector` of `L_FullQuote` objects that is initially sized to 100 objects in the constructor.

```
class L_FullQuote
{
public:
    vector<int> time;
};

class B
{
public:
    // Initialize Symbols with 100 L_FullQuote objects
    B() : Symbols(100)
    {
    }

    std::vector<L_FullQuote> Symbols;

    void handle_message()
    {
       Symbols[i].time.push_back(2);
       // other stuff...
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L_FullQuote *Symbols[100];
```

Here you *declare* an array of pointer to `L_FullQuote`, but you never initialize any of the pointers, so when you call:

```
Symbols[i]->...
```

You are dereferencing an invalid pointer.  Also note that you have declared `time` as private (though your code wouldn't even compile this way, s B as a friend of A I assume?)

Simply declaring an array of pointers does not initialize each element to point to a valid object.  You need to initialize each one, something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    Symbols[i] = new L_FullQuote();
}
```

Only then do you have an array full of valid pointers.  Don't forget to deallocate them though!

Comment: While this does make the code (as written) work, I think given the OP's inexperience, it's not likely that the OP really needs an array of 100 pointers that point off to another memory location, but likely just needs an array of objects to use.

Comment: @Chad: You may be right, I have no idea.  It can't hurt to mention that though, but since you answered I won't change mine.

Answer (score -1):

time is private member of class L_FullQuote, from class B you don't have access to that field